# curve Animation direction of rotation?

Tags: ios, animation, calayer, cakeyframeanimation

In my application I use the following animation to make my UIElement follow a circle path in clockwise direction

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable(); 
CGPathAddArc(path, NULL,viewFormsUI.center.x,viewFormsUI.center.y, 
                     88,radianOf(243),radianOf(0), YES); //viewFormsUI is an UIView 
CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"]; 
[animation setPath:path]; 
[animation setDuration:1];
animation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards; 
[animation setAutoreverses:NO];
CFRelease(path); 
[btnRefreshUI.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"curveAnimation"];
                             //btnRefreshUI is an UIButton
```

`radianOf` is a function which convert angle to radians (just return the value of M_PI*(angle/180))

But the problem is that the UIElement is rotating in anti clockwise direction.
I can't find the error in my code, help me out peers.

Comment: What happens if you change `radianOf(0)` to `radianOf(360)`?

Comment: @rmaddy it is  rotating in anticlockwise direction from 0 to 360

Comment: I meant that what happens if you do `CGPathAddArc(path, NULL,viewFormsUI.center.x,viewFormsUI.center.y, 88,radianOf(243),radianOf(360), YES);`

Comment: @rmaddy  still in anti clockwise direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, viewFormsUI.center.x, viewFormsUI.center.y, 88, radianOf(243), radianOf(0), **YES**);

try just change **YES** to **NO**

CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, viewFormsUI.center.x, viewFormsUI.center.y, 
                     88, radianOf(243), radianOf(0), **NO**);

this is - bool clockwise